# PostgreSQL Query Performance Issues with Large Datasets

Tags: postgresql, go, pagination

I was performing pagination on a large dataset and trying to get the last page with a page size of 1. Inserted around 900,000 records into my database and tried to query page = 900,000 and pageSize = 1 but the data returned was inconsistent. Sometimes it returns 895,234, 705,495, 900,000, 897,894. The 1 record returned is inconsistent when I tried to make a GET request to the paginated endpoint quickly.

It works perfectly fine if the number of records was 50,000 or 100,000 but it returns inconsistent data when the number of records grow.

I am running my Golang API and PostgreSQL in docker compose. In the logs of docker-compose, I see the following:

```
background worker "parallel worker" (PID 197) exited with exit code 1

[192] ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
[192] LOG:  could not send data to client: Broken pipe
[192] FATAL:  connection to client lost
```

Correct me if I am wrong. Could it be due to insufficient threads that resulted in concurrency issues? I understand there could be some data inconsistency due to the large number of records and also calling the endpoint quickly. I want to understand why this is happening as I have searched online for resources but to no avail.

Is there anyway to prevent this? Do I have to run multiple worker threads in Golang API?

**UPDATE with CODE**

```golang
offset := (page - 1) * pageSize

totalPages := (totalRecords + pageSize - 1) / pageSize
isLastPage := page >= totalPages

if isLastPage {
    offset = (totalPages - 1) * pageSize
}

orders, err := GetByUserId(userId, pageSize, offset)

query := `
    SELECT
        u.first_name,
        u.last_name,
        u.username,
        o.amount
        o.status,
        o.received_date
    FROM orders o
    JOIN users u ON u.id = o.user_id
    WHERE u.user_id = $1
    LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3;
`

rows, _ := db.QueryContext(query, userId, pageSize, offset)
defer rows.Close()

var orders Orders
for rows.Next() {
    var order Order
    if err := rows.Scan(
        &FirstName,
        &LastName,
        &Username,
        &Amount,
        &Status,
        &ReceivedDate,
    ); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    orders = append(orders, Order)
}

return orders
```

**UPDATE**

When using pagination to retrieve records from database, it is essential to use `ORDER BY` with `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` to optimize the query performance. After adding an `ORDER BY` statement, the record was retrieved correctly.

```golang
ORDER BY o.received_date
```

Comment: can you add some gap between Api calls, as in ideal cases, once you have received and rendered a data set , then only you fetch the next data set

Comment: connection lost means your timeout was to short, you should check for locks , optimize the query or increase the time out

Comment: @nbk I am only selecting 1 record via pagination SELECT query with OFFSET and LIMIT. Why does it crash even with 1 record?

Comment: i don't know, your query could be complex or as i mentioned there was a lock, look for it

Comment: Why is there no code in this question? To be able to determine the cause of the problem (if there is one), not only is the code querying the database important, but also the DDL used to declare the relation and all its associated objects, like indexes.

Comment: @mkopriva I have included the short snippet of the code in the question, hope this helps! it was a basic pagination query that's why I did not include any code, my apologies

Comment: You're not using any order-by, without order-by the order is not guaranteed, so do not be surprised if the last record of the last page is not identical across multiple queires.

Comment: @mkopriva My apologies, I have included the full code. It is a basic way of retrieving the `rows`, from that, could you show me what I need to include in the attached code?

Comment: https://postgresql.org/docs/15/interactive/sql-select.html *"If the ORDER BY clause is specified, the returned rows are sorted in the specified order. __If ORDER BY is not given, the rows are returned in whatever order the system finds fastest to produce__."*

Comment: @mkopriva Okay, but I am not sure what to `ORDER BY` though because I don't really need any sorting

Comment: *"I don't really need any sorting"* -- If you don't need any sorting why do you care what the last record of the last page is? Without sorting how do you determine what the _correct_ last record of the last page is?

Comment: @mkopriva Ahh okay I see your point. I wanted to return the last few records from the SELECT query if the user enters a high page number that is outside the range of the total number of pages, that's why I never though of any sorting.

Comment: The number of GO threads will only affect the query performance if multiple threads are making calls to the database concurrently. To help determine why the query is performing poorly, run it with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS, VERBOSE)`. Paginating with `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` can be problematic with large datasets (see [Laurenz Albe's article on pagination and page count](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/pagination-problem-total-result-count/)).

Comment: @JohnH Oh okay, this sounds like what I am looking for! Will do more research in this area of paginating a huge dataset! thanks

Comment: LIMIT-ing without ORDER-ing rarely makes sense.

Comment: "...I wanted to return the last few records..." -- In relational tables rows do not have inherent ordering. There's no such thing as the *first*, *second*, or *last* rows.

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes, `ORDER BY` works! Will be upvoting all of your responses and my original answer for others to learn about it